# Is a family of injective holomorphic functions normal family?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a region in $\mathbb{C}$. Set $\mathcal{F}: = \{f \text{ analytic on } \Omega, f \text{ injective}\}$.

1. Is $\mathcal{F}$ normal in $H(\Omega)$( the space of analytic functions on $\Omega$)?
2. Determine the closure of $\mathcal{F}$ in $H(\Omega)$.

The only ideas I could come up with was that all such $f \in \mathcal{F}$ would be bijective and in fact, biholomorphic: $\Omega \rightarrow f(\Omega)$. Now for $\mathcal{F}$ to be a normal family, by Montel's normality criteria, all the functions in $f\in \mathcal{F}$ must miss at least two points(not necessary but sufficient). If they do not miss any point, then $f(\Omega) = \mathbb{C}$ and since $\mathbb{C}$ is biholomorphically equivalent to only itself, hence $\Omega = \mathbb{C}$. This means that $f(z) = az+b$. On the other hand, if a point is missed we can assume $f(\Omega) = \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ or the punctured plane. This is also biholomorphically equivalent to only itself and then $f$ can be only a composition of inversion($1/z$), rotation($e^{i\theta}z$) and dilation ($\lambda z, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \lambda > 0$). I do not see any practical contradiction here.

Comment: Different $f\in \mathcal{F}$ will omit different $a\in\mathbb{C}$. For most $\Omega$, they will all omit uncountably many points, but no point will be omitted by all $f$.

Comment: So then it is not a normal family? Or just that the fundamental criterion cannot be applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The family $\mathcal F$ is not normal. Fix $z_0\in \Omega$ and consider the sequence $f_n(z)=n(z-z_0)$. It converges to $\infty$ at points other than $z_0$, but stays at $0$ at $z_0$.

The closure of $\mathcal F$ consists of the elements of $\mathcal F$ and of constant functions. This is a consequence of [Hurwitz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29): the limit of a sequence of injective holomorphic functions is either injective or constant.

(I interpret limits in the sense of uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\Omega$.)